# Azure toolkit is not working

Tags: maven, azure, intellij-idea

I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot app to Azure using IntelliJ, I started with their formal tutorial about deploying a web app : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/intellij/azure-toolkit-for-intellij-create-hello-world-web-app

I downloaded the toolkit and followed the tutorial step by step , but after I choose the "Run on web app" in the Azure option, no dialog box shows and nothing happens. 
I don't understand where is the problem, any help ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully created a Hello World web app for Azure using IntelliJ:

[image]

I would suggest you to check whether you have missing any prerequisites mentioned in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/intellij/azure-toolkit-for-intellij-create-hello-world-web-app#prerequisites).

Once you have Installed Azure Toolkit for IntelliJ, you should restart IntelliJ and create a new project.

Comment: the problem was with the ToolKit , I reinstalled it and it all worked fine , thank you :)